# GooglePlacesAutocomplete styling on the list content of places is not working,not able to do wrapping the places react-native

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

I m using GooglePlacesAutocomplete where while typing getting the list of places but some places text containing more than that,so I wanted to wrap the text there.

```
 <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='Where To ?'
            minLength={4}
            autoFocus={true}
            listViewDisplayed="auto"
            returnKeyType={'search'}
            fetchDetails={true}
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                props.notifyChange(details.geometry.location,data);
            }}
            query={{
                key: 'chghgdhgfhgfjhdhklkl',
                language: 'en',
            }}
            nearbyPlacesAPI= 'GooglePlacesSearch'
            debounce={200}
            styles={ styles }>
        </GooglePlacesAutocomplete>
```

and  my styles for that is as follows

```
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
textInputContainer:{
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth:0,
    zIndex:999,
    width:'90%',
},
textInput: {
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    height: 45,
    color: '#5d5d5d',
    fontSize: 16,
    borderWidth:1,
    zIndex:999,
  },
  predefinedPlacesDescription: {
    color: '#1faadb'
  },
  listView:{
      top:45.5,
      zIndex:10,
      position: 'absolute',
      color: 'black',
      backgroundColor:"white",
      width:'89%',
  },
  separator:{
    flex: 1,
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  description:{
    flexDirection:"row",
    flexWrap:"wrap",
    fontSize:14,
    maxWidth:'89%',
  },
```

});

refer this link https://reactnativeexample.com/customizable-google-places-autocomplete-component-for-ios-and-android-react-native-apps/
but not able to find the solution.help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The width of the ListView showing the results has its width hardcoded to window.with.  That is why you wrapping the text isn't working.

There is a potential workaround, and that would be to split the description into multiple lines.  You can do this with the [`renderRow`](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete#props) prop. Styling would need to be adjusted for your specific use case.

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='Where To ?'
            minLength={4}
            autoFocus={true}
            listViewDisplayed="auto"
            returnKeyType={'search'}
            fetchDetails={true}
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                props.notifyChange(details.geometry.location,data);
            }}
            query={{
                key: 'chghgdhgfhgfjhdhklkl',
                language: 'en',
            }}
            nearbyPlacesAPI= 'GooglePlacesSearch'
            debounce={200}
            renderRow={(rowData) => {
            const title = rowData.structured_formatting.main_text;
            const address = rowData.structured_formatting.secondary_text;
            return (
             <View>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{title}</Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{address}</Text>
             </View>
             );
            }}
            styles={ styles }>
        </GooglePlacesAutocomplete>
```

You would need to add `row` to your styles and you can `description` from styles, because it is being overwritten by `renderRow`

```
row: {
 height: "100%",
},
```

Disclosure: I am the maintainer of this package.

Comment: perfectly it started working ,thank you so much you have created a nice package.one more thing for styling i should use description or row

Comment: You would need to style the `View` and `Text` inside renderRow separately.  You can either style them inline or create a separate style in the style object.

Comment: Hi Steven, can we add an avatar icon inside the text box, as we do have in google map

Comment: not 100% sure what you mean, but it sounds like you may be looking for the `renderRow` prop. See the readme.

Comment: renderRow prop is meant for the list of places which show up, I'm looking into the text box in which we type, there I wanted to have an avatar icon

Comment: use the `renderLeftButton` prop.

Answer (score 1):

You can even style the field too.

Follow official doc-

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  placeholder='Enter Location'
  minLength={2}
  autoFocus={false}
  returnKeyType={'default'}
  fetchDetails={true}
  styles={{
    textInputContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'grey',
    },
    textInput: {
      height: 38,
      color: '#5d5d5d',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    predefinedPlacesDescription: {
      color: '#1faadb',
    },
  }}
/>
```